# how to add padding to my alacritty terminal in awesomeWM

Tags: terminal, archlinux, awesome-wm, alacritty

So, Im slowly learning lua, awesomewm, and how to configure my os. Now I have a beautiful terminal, but it has no padding, so characters basically touch the edge and its not very aesthetic. Im not sure if I should configure my rc.lua (awesomewm config file) or the alacritty config file. Here is a picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/la5AV.png

EDIT:

```
     ¦ -- Terminal config
     ¦ {
     ¦   ¦ rule_any = {
     ¦   ¦   ¦ class = {
     ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦ "Alacritty",
     ¦   ¦   ¦ },
     ¦   ¦ }, properties = {beautiful.useless_gap = 200}
     ¦ },
```

I just tried this snippet but it returns an error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're likely looking for Alacritty's [padding options](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/blob/6d8db6b9dfadd6164c4be7a053f25db8ef6b7998/alacritty.yml#L44-L50).

```yaml
window:
  padding:
   x: 0
   y: 0
```

Increasing `gap`s in Awesome will increase the space between windows, but it won't change anything about what a single window renders inside its boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to adding a "gap" to the "tag layout". See https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/core_components/tag.html#gap . The easiest way is to set this theme variable https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/core_components/tag.html#beautiful.useless_gap